# Bottom sheet menu bar like whatsapp

Tags: android, xml, keyboard, bottom-sheet

I tried to implement bottom sheet like whatsapp in my chat app.

[image: Menu when Keyboard open][image: Menu when Keyboard close][image: Menu closing effect when keyboard closed][image: Menu closing effect when keyboard open]

Keyboard close when we tap anywhere on screen and when keyboard opens it override with menu and when we touch anywhere keyboard stayed open and close menu.

I implement bottom sheet in fragment like this

```
public class Menu_BottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
public static final String TAG="###Bottom###";
BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback callback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View view, int i) {
        if (i==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN){
            dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View view, float v) {

    }
};


@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    //super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View view=View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.menu_bottomsheet,null);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    TextView button1=view.findViewById(R.id.test1);
    TextView button2=view.findViewById(R.id.test2);
    TextView button3=view.findViewById(R.id.test3);
    TextView button4=view.findViewById(R.id.test4);
    TextView button5=view.findViewById(R.id.test5);
    TextView button6=view.findViewById(R.id.test6);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    button5.setOnClickListener(this);
    button6.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()){
        // BOTTOM SHEET MENU CLICK HANDLES
        case R.id.test1:
            Log.d(TAG,"Button 1 Clicked");
            break;

        case R.id.test2:
            Log.d(TAG,"Button 2 Clicked");
            break;

        case R.id.test3:
            Log.d(TAG,"Button 3 Clicked");
            break;

        case R.id.test4:
            Log.d(TAG,"Button 4 Clicked");
            break;

        case R.id.test5:
            Log.d(TAG,"Button 5 Clicked");
            break;

        case R.id.test6:
            Log.d(TAG,"Button 6 Clicked");
            break;
    }

}
```

Showing bottomsheet in activity like this

```
Menu_BottomSheet bottomSheet=new Menu_BottomSheet();
            bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),bottomSheet.getTag());
```

My bottom sheet close keyboard when pressed with open keyboard also its doesn't have smooth effects when open or close.

[image: My bottom sheets]

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: can you share XML file of this activity?

Comment: Check out this blog: http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-circular-reveal-effect-like-in-whatsapp.html

Comment: @TusharGogna sorry for late reply. I find a way to get above result without any lib but still need to implement. Will update you. The tutorial you posted in comment, they using third party library which i don't want to use and there is alot lib for this. i want to achieve this without any library

Comment: @AbhinavGupta i will update with better here with desired result.

Comment: I did manage to make it but when the keypad is open then it's still opening on top of it. Not sure how Whatsapp did that.

Comment: @Ritu: Have you found any solution without lib? it would be great if you share your solution.

Comment: Any solution to this please @Ritu

Comment: @HiteshDhamshaniya will update in next week.

Comment: @TusharGogna your shared link is broken, page is showing 'Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist.' error. Please update the link or remove it. Thanks.